Counting instances of a key anywheree in a JSON tree
I have a JSON structure in the likes of
{
 "a": {"b": "value"},
 "c": {"b": "value"},
 "d": {"b": "value"}, 
 "e": {"e": {"b": ["value"]}}
}

And I want to know how many times the key "b" is used anywhere in the tree structure. In this case, the expected answer would be 4.
In XML, I could have used XPath to count the number of elements. Is there a JS/JSON-native way to do this other than iterating over each field's keys?

That's not a "JSON structure"  but a JS object. Whereas there is no JS Object with duplicate keys, duplicated keys are allowed (allthough not recommended) in JSON.  What happens when parsing such a JSON-string with duplicated keys to a JS object is up to the parser. Typically, the last occurence is used...

Right, it is a JS Object, good point. And I didn't mean to have duplicate keys - I fixed that.

There is: call JSON.stringify on your object with a replacer function as second argument, the use of which radically changes what the stringify function does. Instead of simply acting as "a string generator", by using a replacer function you turn it into a "do whatever you want with any and all key/value pairs while walking an object tree" utility function:


const data = {
 "a": {"b": "value"},
 "c": {"b": "value"},
 "d": {"b": "value"}, 
 "e": {"e": {"b": ["value"]}}
};

let count = 0;

JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => {
  if (key === `b`) count++;
  return value;
});

console.log(`there are ${count} bees`);




the last "duplicate" was a typo. I fixed it

So this is the answer I was looking for, thanks

This answer takes into consideration that the duplicate keys are part of the problem.
First things first, there is a problem with your JSON - it is invalid. An example code to recursively check for the keys like:
function countKeys(searchKey, obj) {
 let counter = 0;
 for (const key in obj) {
    if (key === searchKey) {
        counter++;
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        counter += countKeys(searchKey, obj[key]);
    }
 }
 return counter;
}

would return 3 for "b", simply because only one of the "a" keys will be considered.
Even if you use regex with JSON.stringify, the stringification only returns valid JSON strings, which means you will also lose the duplicated keys.
console.log((JSON.stringify(keys).match(/"b":/g) || []));
// logs Array(3) [ '"b":', '"b":', '"b":' ]

Possible solutions are:

Make sure your backend returns a valid JSON;
Keep the JSON as a string (if it is a fetch response, for example, do not use .json() on it) then use the regex.

Let me know if this helps!

note that the duplicates were apparently a typo. But even then, use JSON.stringify with a replacer function. Tree walking is literally what it exists for, there is no need to ever write your own object iteration code if you just want to "check all key/value pairs anywhere in the tree".
